# NameError: name 'pyaudio' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hace algún tiempo hice un programa para un asistente de voz en Python, he cambiado el PC e instalado todas las librerías, pero por algún motivo, cuando trato de ejecutarlo me devuelve el error:

```
PS K:\programación\Python\PC IA\Bernat>  & 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Inderlard\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1159798656\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '49997' '--' 'k:\programación\Python\PC IA\Bernat\Asistente.py' 
    C:\Users\Inderlard\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
      warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "k:\programación\Python\PC IA\Bernat\Asistente.py", line 14, in <module>  
        from reconogizer import recon
      File "k:\programación\Python\PC IA\Bernat\reconogizer.py", line 20, in <module>
        FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    NameError: name 'pyaudio' is not defined
```

El problema me lo marca en la linea 20.

```
    # Lybraries:
    import os
    import time
    import wave
    from array import array
    from struct import pack
    from sys import byteorder
    #import numpy as np
    #import pyaudio
    import speech_recognition as sr
    import win32serviceutil
    from matplotlib import pylab
    from pydub import AudioSegment
    
    
    # Program variables:
    THRESHOLD = 500 
    CHUNK_SIZE = 1024
    CHUNK_SIZE_PLAY = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 # Aquí esta el fallo
    RATE = 44100
    MAXIMUM = 16384
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explicación NameError

El error es claro: `NameError: name 'pyaudio' is not defined`, se puede replicar de la siguiente forma

```
variable_1 = 1
print(variable_2)
```

**Salida:**  `NameError: name 'variable_2' is not defined`.

El error te está diciendo, "Estas llamando a una variable que no está definida, es decir, que no existe". Al no existir no se puede utilizar.

### Tu problema

Entendiendo la base del error que es que `pyaudio` no existe, ahora hay que averiguar porque no existe.

En Python **la almoadilla `#` se utiliza para comentar el código** y la linea en la que ejecutas `import pyaudio` está comentada, cuando una linea está comentada, Python al compilar y ejecutar no la procesa. Deberías quedarla así: `import pyaudio`

Comment: Vale... Ahora se me cae la cara de verguenza jajajaja, he revisado el codigo un monton de veces y no me he dado cuenta de algo tan tonto, jajaja, perdona y mil gracias